# c# rotate a gif in a picturebox with a windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm currently doing a windows form with visual studio in C#, and i have two picture boxes in it. First, I used two static pictures (JPG), and i had my original picture on the left, and my 90rotated image on the right. I used the rotateflip method to do it; 
When I tried the same with a gif, the left gif was animated, while the right gif was rotated but was paused.

Maybe it justs rotate the first image of the gif ? I can't find out how to resolve this. Thank you in advance for any help.

Here is the code to rotate the gif :

```
Image down_img = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox3.Image")));
down_img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
this.pictureBox3.Image = down_img;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flipping X coords of an Animated GIF in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865539/flipping-x-coords-of-an-animated-gif-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thank you but i don't try to save a gif or encode it, just rotate each frame of it and then save it.